# problems with operators in url in Retrofit 2

Tags: android, rest, url, retrofit2

I'm trying to learn how to use Retrofit2, and this is the URL I have to generate:

`(baseUrl)/repositories?q=language:Python&sort=stars&page=1`

This is the method I'm using:

```
Call<List<Repo>> javaRepos(
            @Query("language") String language,
            @Query("sort") String sort,
            @Query("page") int page
    );
```

and this is how I'm calling it:

`Call<List<Repo>> call = client.javaRepos("Python", "stars", 1);`

However, this is the url my code generates:

`(baseUrl)/repositories?language=Python&sort=stars&page=1`

The differences are:

- the `q=` is missing;
- `language` is followed by a `=` instead of a `:`

How can I generate the correct url using `@Query` parameters (or any other way, actually)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're misinterpreting the query string of your desired url.

`q=language:Python&sort=stars&page=1` should be broken down into three key-value pairs:

- `q` - `language:Python`
- `sort` - `stars`
- `page` - `1`

Note that the first key is `q` and not `language`.

With that in mind, your method should look like this (and you'll have to pass `"language:Python"` instead of just `"Python"` as the first argument).

```
Call<List<Repo>> javaRepos(
        @Query("q") String language,
        @Query("sort") String sort,
        @Query("page") int page
);
```

Comment: Well, that's embarassing, :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Path annotation according to this link : https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html

```
@GET("repositories?q=language:{lang}&sort={sort}&page={page}")
Call<List<Repo>> javaRepos(@Path(value = "lang") String lang, @Path(value = "sort") String sort, @Path(value = "page") int page);
```